# Cmake include header only target from header only target

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to setup cmake so that I can have a header only library that depends on another header only library. My directory structure looks like this.

```
library_a
|_ a.hpp
library_b
|_ b.hpp
library_c
|_ c.hpp
|_ c.cpp
```

I have my `CMakeLists.txt` setup as follows

Directory root:

```
add_subdirectory(library_a)
add_subdirectory(library_b)
add_subdirectory(library_c)
```

`library_a` directory

```
add_library(target_a INTERFACE)
target_sources(target_a INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.hpp>)
target_include_directories(target_a INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)
```

`library_b` directory

```
add_library(target_b INTERFACE)
target_sources(target_b INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/b.hpp>)
target_include_directories(target_b INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)
target_link_library(target_b INTERFACE target_a)
```

`library_c` directory

```
add_library(target_c STATIC)
target_sources(korc_node_context
               PUBLIC    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/c.cpp>
               INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/c.hpp>)

target_include_directories(target_c INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)

target_link_libraries(target_c INTERFACE target_b)
```

Target `library_a` is meant to be the generic interface to the `library_b` implementation. Eventually there will be more implementations. So in `c.hpp` I include the `a.hpp` header and use `b.hpp` in the `c.cpp` implementation.

Everything configures fine, but when I go to compile, I get an error that the `a.hpp` file cannot be found.

How can I get `target_link_libraries(target_c INTERFACE target_b)` to include the headers from `target_a`?

Answer (score 0):

(As already mentioned in the comments), the issue is that your non-header-only library target `target_c` is being specified saying that its *interface* and ***only*** its interface depends on your header-only-target `target_b` (and transitively on `target_a`), when your `target_c` *itself* also (or only?) depends on `target_b`.

If the interface of `target_c` does not depend on `target_a` (transitively through `target_b`- i.e. users of `target_c` do not need to use anything from the interface of `target_a`), then use `PRIVATE` when linking `target_b` to `target_c`. Otherwise, use `PUBLIC` (which is the combination of `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE`).

For more information, see the reference documentation for [the `target_link_libraries()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).